# Custom message inside the webgrid if empty Using Asp.net Mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I would like to display a message "No Records are Not Found" inside the web grid in the else statement below. Can someone help me with this?

```
<%      
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "ProjectName", rowsPerPage: 5);
using (Html.BeginForm())
{ %> 
    <div class="resourcereprtsmain">
    <%:Html.Label("Project Name") %>
    <%: Html.DropDownList("Projects", (SelectList)ViewBag.Projects, "--Select Project--")%>   
    <br />
    <%:Html.Label("Release Phase") %>
    <%:Html.DropDownList("ReleasePhase", "--Select ReleasePhase--")%>                                      

    <input type="submit" value="search" />                            
    </div>                                                                  
    <div id="grid">
    <%:grid.GetHtml(
     tableStyle: "listing-border_c", headerStyle: "gridhead", footerStyle: "paging", rowStyle: "td-dark", alternatingRowStyle: "td-light",                            
     columns:grid.Columns(
     grid.Column("ProjectName", "Project Name"),
     grid.Column("ReleasePhase", "ReleasePhase"),
     grid.Column("Newbugs", "New Bugs"),
     grid.Column("Assignedbugs", "Assigned Bugs"),
     grid.Column("Fixedbugs", "Fixed Bugs"),
     grid.Column("Reopenedbugs", "Reopened Bugs"),
     grid.Column("Closedbugs", "Closed Bugs"),
     grid.Column("Defferedbugs", "Deffered Bugs"),
     grid.Column("NotaBug", "Not a Bug")                           
      ))%>
    </div>                  
<%} %>
```

Comment: *"...grid in the else statement below"* What else statement? I dont see any.

Comment: @Mohayemin..If GridView  in No Data then message show the No records are found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In Controller code

```
      if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {

                TempData["notice"] = "No Records are Not Found";

            }
            else
            {

            }
```

### In View code

```
<% if (TempData["notice"] != null) { %>
<p><label id="msgtext" >No Records Are Not found !!!!</label></p>
 <% } %>
```

I got Answer